# После использования tqdm пропадает символ

Tags: python

После использования tqdm прогресс бара пропадает первый символ выведенный в консоль. Как исправить это?

И как реализовать такое условие:

```
pbar = tqdm(total=len(data))
for item in data:
    pbar.update(1)

# как проверить завершился прогресс бар или нет
if pbar == 100% или завершен
```

UDP:Пример с пропаданием символа на каждой итерации:

```
import tqdm
from time import sleep
list = [1,2,3]
for i in tqdm.tqdm(list, 'Test'):
    sleep(1)
    print(str(i))

print("Result")
```

В данном примере, вывода внутри цикла не будет, так как он состоит из одного символа, который исчезает чудесным образом.

Но обычно, у меня пропадает символ после всех итераций. В данном примере у меня пропала бы буква "R". Если получится, постараюсь привести пример

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт символа не понял, покажите пример. А проверку на 100% можно сделать например так:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

data = range(1000)

with tqdm(total=len(data)) as pbar:
    for item in data:
        pbar.update(1)

if pbar.n == len(data):
    print('100%')
```

Только нужно не забывать делать `pbar.close()` и лучше с помощью `with ...`.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас напишу пример, с пропаданием символа